# officedown::rdocx_document showing no number in figure and table captions

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, officedown

The number is not appearing in the table and figure captions. For example, even if I compile a default document in r studio i.e. New File -> R Markdown... -> From Template -> Advanced Word Document, and then knit the document, I see missing table and figure numbers.

[image]

[image]

Session info:

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnT6p.png) C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.1
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlffc.png) C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.3/library

I have also tried with [block_caption](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/officer/versions/0.4.2/topics/block_caption) but the problem remains unchanged.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Thank a lot in advance.

Comment: Didn't you forget to update the Word computer field (as explained at https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/faq.html#update-fields) ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @David. Yes, you are absolutely correct. I am using windows, so pressed "Ctrl+A" followed by "F9", and everything worked as expected. Maybe you can write the answer and I will accept that to close the question.